# JSX not parsing React.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

So this common error pops up in my react app, JSX isnt parsing through webpack. I have researched a dozen possible answers but to no avail, I'm trying to avoid using a .babelrc file cause my mac keeps hiding it and i'd rather use the query key anyhows.

```
render: function() {
        return {    
                <div>Hello World</div>
                ^
        }
    } 
Module build failed: SyntaxError:
```

webpack.config.js

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {

    entry: ['./app/index.js'],

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },

    devServer: {
        inline: true,   
        port: 3333
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: 'babel', 
                query: {
                    presets: ['react']          
                }
            }
     ]
},

    plugins: [HtmlWebpackPluginConfig]

}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "github_battle",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.7",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with { which should be (

```
render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Hello World</div>
    );
  }
```

Now it should not throw any error.

Comment: My bad, I run the code you provided and it compiles fine with babel. The issue is in the code. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for that :-), here i was debugging the crap out of my webpack.config, good spotting.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an object that you try to inject your JSX into. That won't work.
You can always wrap your JSX in parenthesis, but it's not required.

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return <div>Hello</div>;
    }
});
```